# Is there a method to display data from api where the id key is taken from another key?

Tags: json, angular, api, angular7

JSON Data:

```
"abcd":[
      {
        "id":"1",
        "cityId":"2",
      },
      {
        "id":"2",
        "cityId":"3",
      }         
],

"city":[
      {
        "id":"2",
        "cityName":"california"
      },
      {
        "id":"3",
        "cityName":"vicecity"
      }
]
```

Angular:

```
<div *ngFor="let clg of abcd$">
  <p>
 {{clg.cityId}} 
<!-- Here i need to print the cityname from city by using the cityId we have got from abcd -->

  </p>
</div>
```

app.component.ts:

```
ngOnInit() {

    this.data.getColleges().subscribe(
      data => this.abcd$ = data
    )
}
```

fetching data from "abcd" is perfectly working....and no problem in fetching the datas from "city" too. But is it possible to fetch the cityName from "city" by using the cityId key from the "abcd" section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a method to get city by ID:

app.component.ts:

```
getCityByID = (cityID) => {
  return this.city$.find(item => item.id === cityID);
}
```

Template:

```
<div *ngFor="let clg of abcd$">
  <p>

    {{ clg.cityId }} 

    {{ getCityByID(clg.cityId).cityName }}

  </p>
</div>
```

**Update**

As far as I understand, you are fetching colleges and cities with 2 separate observables. Because of this, when you are trying to get city by ID, it may (or may not) throw an error if second observable has not been resolved yet. So, you need to combine/join these two streams together. I prefer `combineLatest` to do this but `forkJoin` will work as well.

In app.component.ts:

```
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
......

ngOnInit() {

    combineLatest(
         this.data.getColleges(),
         this.data.getCity()
    ).subscribe(([colleges, cities]) => {
         this.abcd$ = colleges;
         this.city$ = cities;
     });
}
```

This way, you make sure that both `abcd$` and `city$` are inited. Hope this helps.

For further reading:

combineLatest: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html

forkJoin: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/forkjoin.html

Comment: getting this error..!!
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

Comment: You need to fill `city$` as you fill `abcd$`

Comment: this.data.getCity().subscribe(data => this.city$ = data);
i have...but even then i get this error....but the thing is ... the value is displayed...but getting the same error in the console

Comment: Glad to help :)